# Why does the UI become non-responsive even though I'm using an async method?

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, xamarin

I'm currently developing an Android app using the Xamarin framework, so I'm writing it in c#. In this app I'm fetching data from a REST-api, like this:

```
//Method implemented from interface IOnScrollListener
public async void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
{
  //lots of other stuff that's not important for this example
  List<Message> messageList = await PopulateMessagebox(arg1, arg2));
}
```

The method is being called when you reach the bottom of a list (hence the IOnScrollListener implementation). However; the screen freezes when I reach the bottom, and the method is being invoked. And I'm curious as to how this can be, considering I'm using an ansync method call? Shouldn't it run on another thread, allowing the main thread to be uninterrupted/not having to wait?

How would I go about fixing this, so that the app would be responsive while it, in the background, fetches additional info from the API?

Edit: Here's the populateMessageBox-method

```
public async Task<List<Message>> PopulateMessagebox(Constants.MMBType type, int skipSize)
    {
        string messagesJson = await _dal.GetMessageBox(type, skipSize, url);
        var mess = new List<Message>();

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messagesJson))
            {
                mess = Serializer.DeserializeMessagebox(messagesJson);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Logg("Failed to de-serialize the messagebox:" + e);
            throw new AppException(ErrorMessages.SerializationError);
        }
        return mess;
    }
```

---

```
public async Task<string> GetMessageBox(Constants.MMBType type, int skipSize, string url)
        {
            return await GetMessageBoxJSON(type, skipSize, url);

        }
```

--

```
private async Task<string> GetMessageBoxJSON(Constants.MMBType type, int skipSize, string url)
        {
            string res = null;

            if (type == Constants.MMBType.Messagebox)
            {
                string param = string.Format("?$filter=Status ne '{0}' and Status ne '{1}'&$skip={2}",
                    Constants.NO.Nob.Status.Sent, Constants.NO.Nob.Status.SentCorres, skipSize);

                string request = url + param;

                res = await DownloadAndHandle(request);
            }
```

---

And a couple more calls like this, ends us up here:

```
protected virtual async Task<string> SetupAndDownloadString(string uri)
        {
            string responseText;

            if (Session.CookieJar.Size() > 0)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
                request.Headers.Add("ApiKey", AppContext.ApiKey);
                request.Headers.Add("Accept", Constants.ApiFormat);
                request.Headers.Add("Cookie", Session.CookieJar.ToString());

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                responseText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new AppException(ErrorMessages.InsufficientAuthorization);
            }

            return responseText;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show code that calls this method?

Comment: `async`/`await` does not cause another thread to get created. What is the content of `PopulateMessagebox`?

Comment: Edited the PopulateMessagebox method into my question.

Comment: ...and down the rabbit hole we go. Can you show us `GetMessageBox`? You need to show us the code that actually performs an asynchronous operation (via `Task`s, `Thread`s, or other calls into the BCL..).

Comment: Let's cut to the chase, try `await Task.Run(async () => await PopulateMessagebox(arg1, arg2));`

Comment: Well for starters this is blocking: `responseText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`. Perhaps `await` that call too (instead of checking the `Result` property) and see if that improves anything (can't imagine it will.. but worth a shot).

Comment: Where's DownloadAndHandle? -- nvm, saw the comments

Comment: I tried awaiting ReadAsStringAsync() - this did not fix my issue.

When I tried mike z's suggestion, multiple threads just kept on being created - and the entire app froze.

Comment: Then step through your code. Where is the performance actually degrading? Where does your code sit the longest? That's where you should focus your attention

Comment: Thanks. I stepped through my code very carefully now, found out the code flow wasnt quite as expected.